# Haskell type results in "parse error on input ':'"

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Last three lines generate an error. How do I get the types of those expressions without getting an error? Please and thank you.

```
--
-- pairs of Int
--

data Pair = P Int Int deriving (Show, Eq)

pairFst (P x y ) = x
pairSnd (P x y ) = y

instance Ord Pair where
  compare (P x1 y1) (P x2 y2) = 
    case compare x1 x2 of EQ -> compare y1 y2
                          LT -> LT
                          GT -> GT
--
-- pairs of things of type a
--

data Pair a = P a a deriving (Show, Eq)

pairFst (P x y ) = x
pairSnd (P x y ) = y

-- ordering on same kinds of pairs pairs of the same type of thing

instance Ord a => Ord (Pair a) where
  compare (P x1 y1) (P x2 y2) = 
    case compare x1 x2 of EQ -> compare y1 y2
                          LT -> LT
                          GT -> GT
--
-- pairs of things of type a and b
--

data Pair a b = P a b deriving (Show, Eq)

pairFst (P x y ) = x
pairSnd (P x y ) = y

-- ordering on same kinds of pairs pairs of the same type of thing

instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (Pair a b) where
  compare (P x1 y1) (P x2 y2) = 
    case compare x1 x2 of EQ -> compare y1 y2
                          LT -> LT
                          GT -> GT
--
-- pairs of things of type a and b, automatic deriving
--

data Pair a b = P a b deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

pairFst (P x y ) = x
pairSnd (P x y ) = y

:t (<) P 1 2
:t (<) P 1 'a'
:t (<) P 1 "a"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't get the compiler itself to spew out the types at compile time easily and the types have been erased at runtime. Instead, use GHCi. Remove the offending `:t` lines from your file, and run

```
$ ghci WhateverFile.hs
 *> :t (<) P 1 2
 ...
```

As a hint, the answer is "Nothing, it's a type error" since you forgot the parens. I think you wanted

```
(<) (P 1 2)
```

which should have the type

```
 (Num a, Num b) => P a b -> Bool
```

or some less generic version of it.

Comment: For the line "(<) (P 1 2)" I get the error "naked expression at the top level". Any idea why?

Comment: @PaulKar. You have to remove the whole line, Haskell doesn't allow expressions at the toplevel

Comment: Okay. Thanks. That got rid of that error. Btw what do you mean by toplevel? Is it the code that runs during compile time?

Comment: @PaulKar. No, no code is run during compile time it's just code not attached to any declaration (on the right of an `=`)